# $n^2+n$ is even

Tags: proof-writing

If $n$ is a positive integer, then $n^2+n$ is even.

$n=2k$ for some k in the integers

$n^2 +n$ = $4k^2 + 2k$ = $2(2k^2+k)$

as $2k^2+k$ is an integer $n^2+n$ is even.

Jst wondering if this proof is ok. AM i allowed to say $2k^2+k$ is an integer? Thanks

Comment: "AM I allowed to say $2k^2+ k$ is an integer?"  Yes, of course  The set of integers is "closed" under both addition and multiplication.    But it is much simpler say that $n^2+ n= n(n+ 1)$.  Do you see that one of n or n+1 must be even so that the product is even.

Comment: The main parts are fine but I would start by saying: “suppose n is even. Then n=2k...” as the answer below indicates you also have to consider what happens if n is odd. And yes, $2k^2 +k$ Is an integer by the integer axioms, so you can just state it.

Comment: @user247327 Yeah that is easier isnt it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider a case where n is odd... n = 2k + 1

Comment: Oh yeah of course thanks

Comment: **And** you have to prove that those two cases are *exhaust* all possibilities, i.e. every integer is even or odd.

Answer (score 1):

You have set $n=2k$ for some k in the integers, so your proof is ok for even $n$.

Now for odd $n$, you can do the same:

set $n=2k+1$ for some k

$n^2 +n$ = $4k^2 + 4k + 2k + 2$ = $2(2k^2+3k  + 1)$

so this is even.

Comment: One also may need to prove that every integer is odd or even, which follows from the division algorithm (divide by $2$ and examine the remainder).

Answer (score 0):

When you say $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$, you're assuming that $n$ is even. That was not part of the given assumptions.

But you have successfully shown that if $n$ is an even integer, then $n^2 + n$ is also even (yes, $2k^2 + k$ is an integer: if you start with an integer, then no amount of multiplication and addition will make it stop being an integer).

You have to check that it also holds for $n$ odd, i.e. $n = 2k+1$.